# XML attributes c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to display the processingStatus and every field node value along with it's corresponding name of the following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<T24 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.temenos.com/T24/OFSML/130" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.temenos.com/T24/OFSML/130 ofsml13.xsd">
  <serviceResponse>
    <ofsTransactionProcessed application="FUNDS.TRANSFER" function="INPUT" operation="VALIDATE" processingStatus="OK" version="BOOK.TRAN.VAL.MCB">
      <transactionId>FT15056T2QLP</transactionId>
      <field mv="1" name="TRANSACTION.TYPE" sv="1">AC</field>
      <field mv="1" name="CURRENCY.MKT.DR" sv="1">1</field>
      <field mv="1" name="DEBIT.CURRENCY" sv="1">USD</field>
      <field mv="1" name="DEBIT.AMOUNT" sv="1">125.00</field>
      <field mv="1" name="DEBIT.VALUE.DATE" sv="1">20150225</field>

    </ofsTransactionProcessed>
  </serviceResponse>
</T24>
```

Can anyone help me please?
my code:
EDITED CODE:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("XML03.xml");
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Attributes["processingStatus"].Value);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: what have you attempted? any search effort?

Comment: @Steve yes please see edit

Comment: now please describe whats wrong with the code along with output/exception you are getting

Comment: I usually use XElement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx for retrieving values from XML. You may want to look into it for this. If you know the names of the attributes, you should have no problems extracting the values and printing them out.

Comment: Please see edited code

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to define a type or several types which reflect the structure of the Xml; the members would have to be endowed with the attributes `XmlElementAttribute` which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and the attribute `XmlAttributeAttribute`, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); if done suitably, the file contents can be deserialized with the `XmlDeserializer` class, which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A detailed explanation on how to use the deserialization facilities can be found in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) official tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "ofsTransactionProcessed").Select(x => new {
                application = (string)x.Attribute("application"),
                function = (string)x.Attribute("function"),
                operation = (string)x.Attribute("operation"),
                processingStatus = (string)x.Attribute("processingStatus"),
                version = (string)x.Attribute("version"),
                transactionId = x.Elements().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "transactionId").Select(z => (string)z).FirstOrDefault(),
                fields = x.Elements().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "field").Select(z => new {
                    mv = (string)z.Attribute("mv"),
                    name = (string)z.Attribute("name"),
                    sv = (string)z.Attribute("sv"),
                    value = (string)z
                }).ToList()
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How big is the xml file? XmlReader isn't needed for small xml files.  What tags repeat?  I can modify code to work with xml reader but need the elements that repeat.  If your input is a string then simply replace Load(FILENAME) with Parse(your xml string).

Comment: How to I output all the results? i.e processingStatus and fields?

Comment: What format?  You can get each property using results.application, results.function, ....  You can get the fields using a foreach like : foreach(var field in fields){ field.mn, field.name, field.sv, and field.vaue}